# CakePHP: Can you globally modify all links to point to another directory?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.0

My CakePHP app lives inside a subdirectory to keep it from crashing into a Wordpress installation that powers part of the website:

```
example.com/ <--root
    /_wp     <--Wordpress installed here
        /page1
        /page2
    /_cake   <--CakePHP installed here
        /page3
        /page4
```

To maintain consistency, I'm using mod_rewrite rules to rewrite URLs from example.com/_cake/pageX to example.com/pageX etc. This basically works, but CakePHP still creates links with /_cake/pageX. So if a user hovers over a link, the "_cake" will show up in the bottom of the browser and of course in the source code.

Is there a way to configure CakePHP to think it's actually in the site root so it creates the desired URLs for links etc?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to configure CakePHP the way you want.

If you create your links with [`HtmlHelper::link`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-HtmlHelper.html#_link) or [`Router::url`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Router.html#_url), you can add a member `$url['base'] = false` to the `$url` array argument. This prevents the `_cake` prefix being inserted in front of the URL.

As an alternative, you can create your own `link()` or `url()` function, which calls `HtmlHelper::link` and always adds `base = false`.

For this to work, you must also have a .htaccess in the document root, which rewrites the requests to their real destination

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /_cake/$0 [L]
```

You must also pay attention to requests destined for the `_wp` directory.

Comment: Interesting. So basically you're saying I cannot do what I want globally, but I can do it on a case-by-case basis. That's not ideal, but at least it's an option.

Comment: @Emerson Yes and no. Maybe there is a way, but I haven't found it. Although, you're not restricted to CakePHP functions, you can create your own link() and use that instead. See updated answer.